# Как осуществить отправку файла через blob

Tags: javascript, blob

Для отправки данных использую плагин vue-upload-file 
Из данных о файле есть только blob. Можно ли из него как то получить информацию

Comment: blob это и есть сам файл.

Comment: ну он открывается только в браузере 
если скопировать ссылку блоба в другом браузере то она не откроется

Comment: Вообще непонятно о чем ты говоришь и что у тебя в итоге за проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob можно перевести в data-url и в дальнейшем использовать в аттрибуте href элементов img на прямую или отрисовать на canvas и пересохранить с необходимым разрешением.